# Find 4 events that are not mutually independent and yet 3 of them are

Tags: probability

I need to provide 4 events $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ so that for every subset $I\subset \{ 1,2,3,4\}, \,|I|<4, $ it holds $\mathbb{P}(\cap_{i\in I}A_i) = \prod_{i \in I} \mathbb{P}(A_i)$ such that the events $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ are not independent.

I wanted to use the following result, if
$\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap...\cap A_{n-1})>0,$ then  $\mathbb{P}(A_1\cap ...\cap A_n) = \mathbb{P}(A_1)\mathbb{P}(A_2|A_1)...\mathbb{P}(A_n|A_1\cap...\cap A_{n-1}),$ but given the hypothesis that the 4 events are not independent, it does not lead to the wanted relation. As far as I can observe, the relation coincides with the definition of mutually independent events. And yet, we are asked to prove the relation for not independent events. Can somebody provide some insight or a solution proposal ? Thanks.

Comment: Your title says he events satisfy mutual indep. condition, yet your stated condition is not the definition of mutual independence. Did you mean $|I|\leq 4$?

Comment: Thanks. I think that in case it were $|I|\leq 4$, it will be the mutual independence condition. Since it is strictly less than 4, I guess it is not contradicting the mutual independence result. But I am not sure.

Comment: Ok -- if you meant $<4$ then you should rework your title because then its entirely possible that $P(\cap_{i=1}^4 A_i) \neq \prod_{i=1}^4 P(A_i)$ -- that would be the place you could get a solution -- a set of events that are independent except when considered jointly.

Comment: cool -- now it makes sense ... +1:)